# AngularJS: $injector:unpr error when using ngAnimate

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to add `ngAnimate` to my angular app dependencies. Here is my angular app file:

```
var carApp = angular.module("carApp", ["ngAnimate"]);
```

Here is my `TableBodyCtrl` controller:

```
carApp.controller("TableBodyCtrl", function($scope, $http){
    $scope.loading = false;
    ...
});
```

Here is my `TablePanelCtrl`:

```
carApp.controller("TablePanelCtrl", function(){
    this.tab = 1;
    ...
});
```

My controller are in different files in the `controller` folder.

Here is the script loads of angular libraries:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
```

Here is the script load of my angular app file:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/carApp.js"></script>
```

Here is the script loads of my controllers:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/controllers/TablePanelCtrl.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/controllers/TableBodyCtrl.js"></script>
```

When I run my web-app I get this error:

```
Unknown provider: $$qProvider <- $$q <- $animate <- $compile

https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/unpr?p0=$$qProvider%20%3C-%20$$q%20%3C-%20$animate%20%3C-%20$compile
```

This error only started to show up after I add `"ngAnimate"` to my angular app dependencies.

**How can I fix that?**

Comment: which angular of angular are you using? Try adding debug version of it to get more info of the error

Comment: Angular-Animate -- AngularJS v1.3.0-build.3317+sha.a1648a7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've set up the exact same setup as you provided in this **[plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/slcYUNfHB1YJtdZyuSuS?p=preview)**,

There are no errors there. What you're doing is correct.

The order of files and the module creation with 'ngAnimate' as dependency

```
var carApp = angular.module("carApp", ["ngAnimate"]);
```

is the right way to do it.

Altough, one point to keep in mind:

from Angularjs **[docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/misc/downloading)**

> There are two types of angular script URLs you can point to, one for
>   development and one for production:
>
> **angular.js** — This is the human-readable, non-minified version,
>   suitable for web development. **angular.min.js** — This is the minified
>   version, which we strongly suggest you use in production.

same goes for angular-animate.js.

This will help you in development while it'll show you better error reports.

Another point is even when using minified angularjs version, you get a link to the 'long descriptive' error msg, and by looking the **[link](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/unpr?p0=$$qProvider%20%3C-%20$$q%20%3C-%20$animate%20%3C-%20$compile)** your provided with your error msg, I saw this:

> An unknown provider error can also be caused by accidentally
>   redefining a module using the angular.module API, as shown in the
>   following example.
>
> ```
> angular.module('myModule', [])
> .service('myCoolService', function () { /* ... */ });
>
> angular.module('myModule', [])
> // myModule has already been created! This is not what you want!
> .directive('myDirective', ['myCoolService', function (myCoolService) {
>   // This directive definition throws unknown provider, because myCoolService
>   // has been destroyed.
> }]);
> ```
>
> **To fix this problem, make sure you only define each module with the angular.module(name, [requires]) syntax once across your entire
>   project. Retrieve it for subsequent use with angular.module(name). The
>   fixed example is shown below.**
>
> ```
> angular.module('myModule', [])
> .service('myCoolService', function () { /* ... */ });
>
> angular.module('myModule')
> .directive('myDirective', ['myCoolService', function (myCoolService) {
>   // This directive definition does not throw unknown provider.
> }]);
> ```

Answer (score 34):

I had the same error and just figured out why it was happening.

The root cause was I was depending on "angular-animate": "~1.3.0", so bower was using Angular v1.3 even though the rest of the project was depending on Angular 1.2.

Just use

```
"angular-animate": "~1.2.0"
```

instead of

```
"angular-animate": "~1.3.0"
```

in your bower.json file. After a `bower install` everything should work!

Same answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26596023/2171509

Comment: Nice one :)  Worth mentioning that bower's own install of angular-animate allows suffixing of @[ng-version], which is recommended.  I'd have avoided this issue if I'd used it.

Comment: Perfect. That was my problem! I was using  AngularJS v1.2.9 with http://..../1.3.3/angular-animate.min.js so I changed to http://..../1.2.9/angular-animate.min.js and with this change worked like a charm

Comment: Thanks!  At this date (sept 2015) this is the case with the Start Angular Versatile AngularJs Theme out of the box.

Comment: ngAnimate version > angular version not works. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

I had same problem,solved by

```
bower update.
```

Comment: Solved problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, the reason seems to be conflict between versions of these libraries.

I didn't see this error after I updated to `AngularJS v1.3.14` from `v 1.2`. Try different versions & check their compatibility.